# Check if record is referenced from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my `SQL Server 2008` db I have 2 tables:

1. `Order`
2. `Customer`

The `Order` table has a FK to `CustomerID`.

I would like to disable the "delete" button in my Customer grid IF the Customer has been used already in 1+ order.

The query is working but can it be improved considering the future growth of the `Order` Table (+ 200.000 records / year)?

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Name, 
       CASE WHEN t.OrderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'HasOrders'
FROM Customer AS c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 OrderID 
    FROM [Order] AS o
    WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
) AS t
```

Comment: why downvote after 5 years? -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that the following query would be the fastest approach, assuming you have an index on `orders(CustomerID)`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Name, 
       (case when exists (select 1 from orders o where o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as HasOrders
FROM Customers c;
```

Your version of the `outer apply` might have the same performance as this.

Two small comments about style.  I would suggest making your table names plurals rather than singular ("customers" and "orders").  This prevents using a reserved word as a table name.  Second, you do not need to quote "HasOrders".  If you did, I would discourage single quotes.  These should be reserved for string constants.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Name, 
       CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Order o
                         WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID ) 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasOrders
FROM Customer AS c
```

This might be more efficient with an index on `CustomerId` since `EXISTS` can short.circuit.